# Mod security rule

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Today I have noticed  a rewrite  rule and its given below. After reading the doc over Apache, I believe it's a rule that redirects anything after the domain name will forcefully redirect to `example.com/index.php?slugname`.

This means if we try  `example.com/abc` in the browser it will redirect to `example.com/index.php?slugname`

Is it correct?. Could you guys tell me what's exactly meant by this rule?

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?slugname=$1 [L]
```

Comment: What dose your quetion has to do with mod security rule?

Answer (score 0):

No the rule will rewrite `example.com/abc` to `example.com/index.php?slugname=abc` if the `.htaccess` file is in `example.com/` but only if the characters after `example.com/`, in your case `abc`, do not include a `/` or a `.`.

In older versions of apache it will not work, because the matching sting is not `abc` but `/abc` (the first `/` is include) and so it can not match.

#### Notice:

It's a rewrite so from the user point of view the URL is still `example.com/abc` in the browser, but internally it is like if the user did request `example.com/index.php?slugname=abc`. If no other Rule is in place both should give the same result.